# Initialize an object c#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I've got an object with a lot of property to be set. What is the best practice in initializing this kind of object?

I've created a static method for example

```
public static Car newCar (BreakModule breakModule, Chassis chassis, Wheel wheel,     Seat seat, Headlight headlight)
{

Car newCar = new Car
{
BreakModule = breakModule,
Chassis = chassis,
Wheel = wheel,
Seat = seat,
Headlight = headlight};

return newCar;
}
```

I thought the best practice is not to have more than 4 parameter pass into a method? If I'm following that, how else could I approach this?

This class itself is from a webservice.cs I've generated from xsd using wsdl tool

Comment: Use 3 tier approach and move the parameters to a Model

Comment: one way or another if your object needs these parameters to be constructed then they need these parameters therefore create the constructor requiring all the parameters... simple. there is no exceptions or excuses here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the class itself should decide what it requires and does not require to operate at a minimum level during creation. The properties that the class *must* have set should be asked for in a constructor. Any other non-required properties can be set as is required.

From this, your `Car` class should have a constructor like the following:

```
public class Car
{
    BreakModule _breakModule;
    Chassis _chassis;
    Wheel _wheel;
    Seat _seat;
    Headlight _headlight;

    public Car(BreakModule breakModule, Chassis chassis,
               Wheel wheel, Seat seat, Headlight headlight)
    {
        this._breakModule = breakModule;
        this._chassis = chassis;
        this._wheel = wheel;
        this._seat = seat;
        this._headlight = headlight;
    }

    private Car()
    {
    }
}
```

Notice the `private constructor` in the above code example. This is to fore the user of the class to pass in the required properties for the class to operate. With a `private constructor`, the user cannot do the following:

```
Car car = new Car(); // not allowed!
```

If your class requires many properties to operate at a minimum level, you can refactor how your class works.

For example, if you feel that your `Car` doesn't need wheels to begin with - perhaps it is stationary, been robbed etc... - then you could add a method such as the following, which would allow you to lessen the amount of parameters required to pass into the constructor to create your class:

```
public void AddWheel(Wheel wheel)
{
    // Add a wheel...
}
```

Comment: is if possible that i use this approach and skip having to pass in the parameter by overloading, instead calling the addmethod to each of the property, for example, somewhere else i have get,set for wheel, then i just call the method

Comment: @overst33r Absolutely! There is nothing wrong with that at all. As long as your class doesn't _require_ those properties to be set during startup (the programmer may forget for instance), then you are fine.

Answer (score 5):

If your car is not complete without all those parameters, there should be a constructor taking all of them. If that's too complicated, I'd be happy to have additional constructors taking less parameters that provide working defaults.

If it's not your class to start with (maybe because it's a POCO generated from a wsdl), I would build a factory class that has the same methods a constructor would provide doing the same job.

Comment: I agree, required properties in the constructor and optional ones as properties. 4 parameters may be a good guide but there are more important principals.